# Why iAd keeps showing "Testing Advertisement"?

Tags: iphone, iad

My app is approved on AppStore. In the iAd section of the screen, it keeps showing the black "Testing Advertisement" by Apple instead of a real ad. Is there any configuration I missed? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do everything [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)?  Also, did you test your application on a different device to see if the ad shows up there correctly?

Comment: In face I use the code from the http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html to build the iAd part.

Comment: Did you set your app up to use iads in iTunes connect?

Comment: Got this "You can only change your iAd Settings when the latest version of your app is in an editable state." message when I try to change anything.

Comment: I uploaded a new version and checked, yes, iAd is enabled.

Comment: It seems to me there is a delay between app approval and the first ad to pop up. Some users reported a real ad is showing.

Answer (score 8):

From the section in the iAd Programming Guide on [Testing Banner Advertisements](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH4-SW14):

> iAd Network automatically displays the
> correct ad depending on the
> application binary:
>
> **Application | Audience | Displayed Ads**
>
> Developer build | Developer | iAd
> Network serves test ads.
>
> Ad-hoc
> distribution build | Beta Testers |
> iAd Network serves test ads.
>
> Signed
> Distribution build | End Users | iAd
> Network serves live ads if you signed
> the iAd Network Agreement and enabled
> advertising for your application.

Therefore, your development and ad hoc builds will only display test advertisements.  Only the distribution build that is submitted to the App Store will display real ads.  Unfortunately, that means that you'll need to wait and download your own application from the store to see real ads in action in your application.

Comment: The original post is concerning an app released on the App Store

Comment: @Kamchatka - Yes, but the responses seemed to indicate that they might have been looking for ads in the local development build of the application, instead of a version that had been downloaded from the App Store.  I know people that have done this and expected real ads to appear in the local developer or ad hoc builds they had after the application itself was approved for the App Store.

Comment: Then why would Apple send me this via Resolution Center: We found that your app and/or its metadata does not appear to include final content, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, your application description contain screenshots with empty iAd banners. It would be appropriate to remove or replace these screenshots. ... which clearly states they don't want test or empty ads!

Comment: @mars - They don't want people serving ads to themselves in local development builds, which can be used to scam the iAds system. I'm not sure why they rejected your screenshots, because I've seen plenty of applications on the store with screenshots that contained Apple's test iAds. You might be able to protest that in the resolution center.

Answer (score 4):

iAd is a very big disappointment. Ads are shown only in certain geographical regions, in other areas system returns nothing after the request (you can check the statistics for your iAd profile in the iTunes Connect). So you won't see anything in the banner in Hong Kong, as I cannot see anything in Korea for the moment. If you want to make money on advertising consider using other ad provider, like admob.

Answer (score 2):

I think even if you download the app from the App Store, the app still shows test ads if you have the developer profile on.  I tried removing it and running the app from the app store and it doesn't show test ads anymore.

Comment: Completely unrelated apps were showing test advertisements until I followed this tip. I temporarily removed all profiles from my device and now see ads in all apps.